# Sorting Rows of a 2D Array in JavaScript Based on Dates in the First Row

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a 2D array in JavaScript where the first row contains date-time strings, and I want to sort all the rows based on the dates in the first row. Here's an example of my array:

```
const data = [
  ['4:23:28 PM', '4:24:01 PM', '4:24:39 PM', '4:26:05 PM'],
  [1, 2, 3, 0],
  [4, 5, 3, 2]
];
```

I've tried a few approaches, but I'm running into issues. Can someone provide a working solution or suggest how I can achieve this? Also, here's the expected output after sorting:

```
const expectedOutput = [
  ['4:26:05 PM', '4:24:39 PM', '4:24:01 PM', '4:23:28 PM'],
  [0, 3, 2, 1],
  [2, 3, 5, 4]
];
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your example is not really well chosen. You want to sort arrays that consist of only the value 1??

Comment: *"I'm running into issues."*: please share your attempt and explain what the issue is.

Comment: A good argument for the 24hr clock

Comment: So now your example comes down to reversing the inner arrays. Is this always your case? If not, can you provide a more representative example?

Comment: Are your time always "PM"? If not, can you provide a more representative example? And, where is your attempt? What is holding you back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach

```js
const data = [
    ["4:23:28 PM", "4:24:01 PM", "4:24:39 PM", "4:26:05 PM"],
    [1, 2, 3, 0],
    [4, 5, 3, 2],
];

const getDate = (timeString) => {
    const [time, ampm] = timeString.split(" ");
    const [hours, minutes, seconds] = time.split(":").map(Number);
    let adjustedHours = hours;

    if (ampm === "PM" && hours !== 12) {
        adjustedHours += 12;
    } else if (ampm === "AM" && hours === 12) {
        adjustedHours = 0;
    }

    return new Date(0, 0, 0, adjustedHours, minutes, seconds);
};

const sortedIndices = data[0]
    .map((time, index) => [index, getDate(time)])
    .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
    .map(([index]) => index);

const transformed = data.map((arr) => sortedIndices.map((index) => arr[index]));

console.log(transformed);
```

Comment: Currently, the `adjustedHours` algorithm has a bug: the expression `ampm === 'PM' && hours !== 12 ? hours + 12 : hours` will produce `12` for times in the range of `12:00:00 AM` to `12:59:59 AM`, but it should actually produce `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in steps:

- Transpose the 2D array
- Sort the rows by their first member. To compare those time strings, parse them into a number of seconds since midnight
- Transpose the sorted 2D array

Here is how it could be done:

```js
const transpose = arr => arr[0].map((_, i) => arr.map(row => row[i]));
const timeOf = str => // Parse "h:mm:ss am" format
    ((h,m,s,p) => ((h % 12) + (p > 'P') * 12) * 3600 + m * 60 + +s)
        (...str.match(/\w+/g));

const data = [
  ['4:23:28 PM', '4:24:01 PM', '4:24:39 PM', '4:26:05 PM'],
  [1, 2, 3, 0],
  [4, 5, 3, 2]
];
const result = transpose(
                  transpose(data)
                  .sort(([a], [b]) => timeOf(b) - timeOf(a)) // reversed
               );
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes, @Alexander, I had sorted in ascending order. Now done in descending order.

Comment: Also, my input was somehow different from what the question has now. Updated it to align, so there is no confusion possible.

Comment: nice one, added to the benchmark

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  ['4:23:28 PM', '4:24:01 PM', '4:24:39 PM', '4:26:05 PM'],
  [1, 2, 3, 0],
  [4, 5, 3, 2]
];

const transformTime = a => a.slice(0,2) === '12' ? 
  (a[a.length - 2] === 'A' ? 'A00' : 'P00') + a.slice(2) : 
  a[a.length - 2] + a.padStart(11, '0');
  
const sortedTime = data[0]
  .map((time, idx) => ({time: transformTime(time), idx}))
  .sort(({time: a}, {time: b}) => a < b ? 1 : a === b ? 0 : -1)
  .map(({idx}) => idx);

const result = data.map(arr => sortedTime.map(idx => arr[idx]));

result.forEach(arr=>console.log(...arr.map(JSON.stringify)));
```

And a benchmark:

```
Cycles: 100000 / Chrome/117
------------------------------------------------------
Alexander        64/min  1.0x   66   72   74   64   76
Abito Prakash   429/min  6.7x  442  446  444  436  429
trincot         509/min  8.0x  548  509  514  530  528
------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark
```

```html
<script benchmark="100000">

const data = [
  ['4:23:28 PM', '4:24:01 PM', '4:24:39 PM', '4:26:05 PM','4:23:28 PM', '4:24:01 PM', '4:24:39 PM', '4:26:05 PM'],
  [1, 2, 3, 0,1, 2, 3, 0],
  [4, 5, 3, 2,1, 2, 3, 0]
];


// @benchmark Abito Prakash
const getDate = (timeString) => {
  const [time, ampm] = timeString.split(' ');
  const [hours, minutes, seconds] = time.split(':').map(Number);
  const adjustedHours = ampm === 'PM' && hours !== 12 ? hours + 12 : hours;
  return new Date(0, 0, 0, adjustedHours, minutes, seconds);
};

const sortedIndices = data[0]
    .map((time, index) => [index, getDate(time)])
    .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
    .map(([index]) => index);
    
data.map((arr) => sortedIndices.map((index) => arr[index]));

// @benchmark trincot
const transpose = arr => arr[0].map((_, i) => arr.map(row => row[i]));
const timeOf = str => // Parse "h:mm:ss am" format
    ((h,m,s,p) => ((h % 12) + (p > 'P') * 12) * 3600 + m * 60 + +s)
        (...str.match(/\w+/g));


transpose(
                  transpose(data)
                  .sort(([a], [b]) => timeOf(b) - timeOf(a)) // reversed
               );

// @benchmark Alexander

    const transformTime = a => a.slice(0,2) === '12' ? 
  (a[a.length - 2] === 'A' ? 'A00' : 'P00') + a.slice(2) : 
  a[a.length - 2] + a.padStart(11, '0');
const sortedTime = data[0].map((time, idx) => ({time: transformTime(time), idx})).sort(({time: a}, {time: b}) => a < b ? 1 : a === b ? 0 : -1).map(({idx}) => idx);
data.map(arr => sortedTime.map(idx => arr[idx]));

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you're going to keep posting benchmarks then you need to run them over more robust data sets. Abito Prakash very quickly surpasses Trincot on even slightly larger arrays. Micro benchmarking like this is often skewed, prone to implementation faults, and doesn't adequately address engine optimization patterns.

Comment: @pilchard i wouldn't agree. running benchmarks on benchmark sites is often skewed since the engine is already optimized some patterns. ideally a page should run only 1 benchmark without any extra code (which will be the next version). and about robust data definition. which amount of data is usually processed by the OP? also not defined. yes, there're 2 types of code, working better on small data sets and working better on larger ones

Comment: @pilchard regarding micro benchmarks they pretty reflect the performance side of code, when for example i replace Object.entries(), where not all values are used, by Object.keys() the performance boost is very noticable, etc.

Comment: @pilchard regarding Abito Prakash i see unnecessary string splits, array mapping and so on. so the algo looks not fast even before benchmarking

Comment: I didn't say they yielded no information, but simply that they should be taken with a grain of salt. I also wasn't commenting on the efficiency or quality of anyone's code, simply a benchmark against an array of 3 elements may not be showing very much, but I'm happy to leave it there.

Comment: Also your sorting isn't working around the 12 hours, you have your AM and PM reversed and if fixed 12pm sorts as later than 1pm. `12:01 AM` is `00:01` 24h and `12:01 PM` is `12:01` 24h.

Comment: @pilchard added 12pm - sorted ok: `['4:23:28 PM', '4:24:01 PM', '4:24:39 PM', '4:26:05 PM', '12:00:00 PM']`. please provide a test data where sorting fails. afaik 12pm < 4pm

Comment: `[ '4:01:00 PM', '12:02:00 PM', '11:03:00 AM', '12:04:00 AM' ]` should remain sorted as they are, but yours yields `"12:04:00 AM" "4:01:00 PM" "11:03:00 AM" "12:02:00 PM"`